# Looking for interesting problems to solve numerically

Tags: numerical-methods, education

I am giving tomorrow an introduction to Python to undergraduates and have to present how it can be used to solve some mathematical problems. I have been looking for some nice or challenging problems to illustrate that, looked quite long on project Euler but did not find something that would fit. May I ask you for suggestions?

Comment: You can do [Geometric Modeling in Shape Space](http://www.dmg.tuwien.ac.at/pottmann/2007/kilian-2007-gmss/paper_docs/shape_space_sig_07.pdf) with python. This has also important medical applications.

Answer (score 1):

Check out https://www.dataquest.io

I think https://www.dataquest.io/course/linear-algebra is what you want.

You can also browse the different [courses](https://www.dataquest.io/course).